# Is there a way to set inset for specific row in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My question is stated in the title. 
I have a need to specify the content inset for specific rows. Reason for this is that i have to make a layout in which the first cell of the first section needs to occupy whole width of the screen, while first cell of the second section needs to have insets of left: 8, right: 8.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQZ8u.png)

Also, with inset set to 0 last cell in the section is positioned completely to the left of the screen. Any suggestions on that?

This is the code for calculating the size:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {


            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 {

            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 36, height: 50)
        } else {
            let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 16, height: 50)
            return size
        }
    } else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 16, height: 100)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 16, height: 50)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 16, height: 50)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why not just have different subclasses of the cells, and design them differently rather than setting a custom inset? Use Xib's to create the Cells, design them and then register them.

Comment: @Jay thanks for replying. I've been trying to implement different cell design but with no success. Still the problem remains. 
And i've encountered several similar questions, mostly regarding the problem with the last cell in section. The problem i have consists of few smaller problems, all of them solvable by having insets for all rows insets set to 8 (left and right), except for row 0 of section 0.
 If you could give me any sample code i would be most grateful.